# Speed of satellite when it falls freely on the surface of the earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, satellites

I am a high school student in my final two years before university. I have a question which I do not know how to approach. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

> "If an artificial satellite is moving in a circular orbit around the earth with a speed equal to half the magnitude of escape velocity from the earth,If the satellite is stopped suddenly in its orbit and allowed to fall freely on to the earth,find the speed with which it hits the surface of earth."

Comment: Is that all the information that you were given?  I am not sure what class 11 means in terms age in your education system and so cannot give a direct answer.  It boils down to whether or not you have covered the idea that the gravitational attraction varies with height above the Earth's surface.

Comment: Sorry,i forgot to mentio one more thing..

Comment: The speed of the satelite gives you the height of the orbit.Then it is simply potential energy. Simple if you can assume gravity is constant, a bit more calculus if you need to consider the change in gravity with height.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Well the practical answer is terminal velocity, which will depend upon shape of the satalite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three pieces to this puzzle.  First you need to derive an equation for the escape velocity of an object launched from the surface of the earth.  Then you need to find the orbital radius of an object orbiting at half the escape velocity.  Then you need to determine how long it takes (neglecting air resistance) for the object to fall from that orbital radius to the surface of the earth.  Do you know how to do any of these things?

Comment: Alternatively for the third step you can use conservation of energy (assuming we're ignoring air resistance and so on).

Comment: Oh.  Thanks.  I forgot that all they were asking for was the speed at which it hit the ground.  Somehow I got it in my head that they were asking for how long it took to fall.